# What does the --production flag do on npm run build?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

On Create-React-App, if I run

```
npm run build --production
```

What exactly is the production flag doing to the final build?

Comment: This is an environment variable, it doesn't do anything unless you specify it in your code that something (typically server URLs, ports, etc) requires it

Comment: Ah, got it. Didn't realize that was an environment variable. Thanks!